# How do I use innerHTML Property in function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to use innerHTML Property as value. I have created a shopping cart , but I  having trouble using the innerHTML Property (which is the total value ) in another function.  I am using a range calcuator to multiply the total value to get a monthly rate.

Check the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nAuyL?editors=101)

I am using this property (which is my price total) (creating the `var rangecalculator` seems to be the problem. How do you use innerhtml in functions ?

```
var rangecalculator = document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerHTML = (((salesTotal-discount12) * (0.13)) + (salesTotal-discount12)).toFixed(2);
```

In this range calculator.

```
    var priceRange = [ 100, 250, 1000, 2500, 5000 ];
    var priceValue = [ 0.23, 0.12, 0.20, 0.19, 0.19 ];

     for(range in priceRange) 
     if (rangecalculator >= priceRange[range]) 
     rateValue = priceValue[range];

     document.getElementById("monthlyrate").innerHTML= rateValue * rangecalulator;
```

I get NAN and undefined. It only works when I set(a number) `var rangecalculator = 100`.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You set a variable called `rateValue` and then use a variable called `rangeValue`.

Comment: In addition to that, your "rangecalculator" value is a string starting with "Your Rate: $", so you can't use it as a number in a multiplication operation.

Comment: `for..in` is purposed to iterate objects. You should use `for` to iterate arrays, especially in your case, where iteration order is important.

Comment: @pointy [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJysb?editors=101) I updated with ur edits still no luck .

Comment: @Teemu I am not having issues with my range calculator  , I am having an issue with      `document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerHTML = "Your Rate: $" + (((salesTotal-discount12) * (0.13)) + (salesTotal-discount12)).toFixed(2);`

Comment: I did look up [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a mess... `rangecalculator` gets string value "Your Rate: $..."

Then, you're comparing `rangecalculator` against numbers:

```
if (rangecalculator >= priceRange[range]) 
    rateValue = priceValue[range];
```

which is never true, and therefore, `rateValue` never gets value and remains undefined, etc...

I presume, you should start your code with:

```
var rangecalculator = (((salesTotal-discount12) * (0.13)) + (salesTotal-discount12)).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerHTML = "Your Rate: $" + rangecalculator;
```

Comment: I am attempting to use that string as the value for `rangecalculator ` here the edit in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJysb?editors=101)